# what can be the sql query?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

I have 2 tables `tbl_UserRegistration` and `tbl_Streaks` with structures like this:

**tbl_UserRegistration**

```
               DATATYPE   LENGTH
UserName       Text         25  (PRIMARY KEY)
PhotoLink      Text        150  
DeviceToken    Integer      15
DeviceType     Integer       1
```

**tbl_Streaks**

```
            DATA TYPE     LENGTH
ID          Integer         10 (PRIMARY KEY)
Player1     Text            25
Player2     Tex             25
Streaks     Integer         10
```

Now I want to fetch players who have highest streak with their photolink.

EDITED :

```
 i.e. Player1, Player2, MAX(streak), Photolink
```

How can I do this?

What can be sql query ?

thanks..

NOTE- `Player1` and `Player2` and `UserName` are equal..

Comment: You mean to say that Player1, Player2 and Usernames always has the same values?? Why do we have 2 columns Player1 and player2 in streaks table, what is the relationship here.

Comment: are there any common fields between the two tables i.e a fiels you can JOIN on?

Comment: do you have any attempts at the SQL you can add to the question please?

Comment: Which flavour of SQL? MSSQL, MYSQL, PLSQL etc. ??

Comment: The problem with this particular output you want is that `PhotoLink` is an attribute of a single player, not of a *pair* of them. So my question is, whose `Photolink` should be displayed, `Player1`'s or `Player2`'s? Or do you perhaps want `Photolink1` and `Photolink2` in the output?

Comment: All right, that much is clear, but do you really want 2 values (2 photolinks) returned in 1 column (`Photolink`)? I really think it would be better to produce two different columns, `Photolink1` and `Photolink2`, one per player, unless there's something about your design that requires that there be one `Photolink` column in the output. If you really want one `Photolink`, how then would you like to return two photolinks in one column?

Comment: @AndriyM - can we not get 2 Photolinks of that 2 players ? Because I want to display those 2 players's username, photolinks and and their streak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve `PhotoLink` for both users by joining to `tbl_UserRegistration` twice. To get the pair of players who scored the most, you could sort the rows in the descending order of `Streak` and limit them to only one row, like this:

```
SELECT
  s.Player1,
  s.Player2,
  s.Streak,
  u1.PhotoLink AS PhotoLink1,
  u2.PhotoLink AS PhotoLink2
FROM tbl_Streaks s
  INNER JOIN tbl_UserRegistration u1 ON u1.UserName = s.Player1
  INNER JOIN tbl_UserRegistration u2 ON u2.UserName = s.Player2
ORDER BY s.Streak DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming Username is the same as Player1 and Player2 then you can JOIN tbl_Streaks onto tbl_UserRegistration and in the SELECT clause find the MAX() of Streaks along with Player1 and Player2

the following is in T-SQL and will pull out the max Streaks per UserName:

```
SELECT
    r.UserName 
    , MAX(s.Streaks) mx     
FROM 
    tbl_UserRegistration r
    INNER JOIN tbl_Streaks s ON
        r.UserName = s.Player1
GROUP BY
    r.UserName
```

Comment: added a small T-SQL example (I don't know MySQL)